# Increase integer when an object is created in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

Hello I have two models **Teaching Semester** and **Enrollments** , i wanted to count the number of students in a particular course. Practically i wanted to have a **registered students** field which will be increased everytime  when **Enrollments** object is created.
Here is my model for **Teaching Semester**

```
class TeachingSemester(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program    = models.ForeignKey(Program,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(FacultyData,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester_choices = (
        ('Spring' , 'Spring'),
        ('Fall'   , 'Fall'),
        ('Summer'  , 'Summer')
    )
    sem_choice = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=semester_choices,default='Spring')
    course_date      =   models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    section          = models.CharField(max_length=5,default = 1)
    faculty_course     = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And model of **Enrollments**

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentData,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(TeachingSemester,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please *don't*. It will result in a lot of trouble to keep the integer correctly updated. For example if later a `StudentData` is removed, it will remove all related `Enrollment`s as well, and thus a lot of `TeachingSemester`s need to be updated accordingly. It can be quite hard to look for every possible scenario, and update the `TeachingSemester` objects accordingly.

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

TeachingSemester.objects.annotate(registered_students=Count('enrollment'))
```

The `TeachingSemester` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.registered_students`.

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: In the views where you need to obtain the number of `registered_students`.

Comment: Your code will result in counting all the enrollments , i want it to count enrollments for particular course.

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: no it will only count the ones *related* to the `TeachingSemester`. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: After Count i have to write model name or what , "enrollment" is not my models name.

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: you made in your question a model named `Enrollment`, so you refer to it in lowercase, so `enrollment`.

Comment: The method didn't work, how can i do this with signals?

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: please *don't* use signals https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html Exactly *what* is not working? What problem do you face? Share the relevant view, template, etc.

Comment: Actually this is the code i am using in the view ` spring_courses = TeachingSemester.objects.filter(
        department=dep.pk,
        program = prog.pk,
        course_date__year__in=[datetime.date.today().year],
        course_date__month__in=[1,2,3, 4, 5],
    )

    fall_courses = TeachingSemester.objects.filter(
        department=dep.pk,
        program = prog.pk,
        course_date__year__in=[datetime.date.today().year],
        course_date__month__in=[7,8,9, 10, 11,12],
    )` Where can i put your code?

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: please edit the question with the full view.

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: @Amiable.Azam: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72626917/edit) the question with the full view code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245686/discussion-between-amiable-azam-and-willem-van-onsem).